# animation frame lineplot plotly doesn't work (python)

Tags: python, animation, plot, plotly, line-plot

I'm trying to create an animated line graph with python and plotly. My data are the years from 1750 to 2018 on the x-axis and on the y-axis I have the world CO2 emissions in billions of tons (from 0 to 35). My animation_frame is on the "year" so we can see the evolution.

Below is my code:

```
fig = px.line(df_emissions_co2_world, x = "year", y = "co2_billions_t",
          animation_frame = "year", 
          title = " CO2 billions t")
```

when I display the graph I don't see any curve appear over any year. However, when I make a simple plotline without the animation I have the desired data with this code :

```
fig = px.line(df_emissions_co2_world, x = "year", y = "co2_billions_t",
          title = " CO2 billions t")
```

Someone would know what the problem is?

Comment: Please share a sample of your data

Answer (score 1):

For me, animations not working but everything else working in Plotly was fixed by changing the renderer from `notebook-connected` to `notebook`.

Here's information on rederers: https://plotly.com/python/renderers/

Here's the code that fixed it for me:

```
# These lines before the animated plotly figure
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = 'notebook'
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me :)