# Choropleth: animation_frame does not working to create the graph on colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, plotly-python, choropleth, plotly-express

I am facing a problem with Cloropleth when I try to use the *animation_frame* and *geojson* together.
If I run my code using the geojson on the **colab**, it generates the graph. However, if I try to animate it, the colab runs out of time and does not generate the graph. I ready tried the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66790071/12461353), but it does not work for me. I am creating my code based on this [tutorial](https://python.plainenglish.io/how-to-create-a-interative-map-using-plotly-express-geojson-to-brazil-in-python-fb5527ae38fc).
Did someone have the same problem?

I am using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen    

df_corona_brio_clean = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Yuri-Nassar/public_datasets/master/coronavirus/source_brasil_io/caso_covid_brio_filtered.csv', sep=';')
df_corona_brio_clean['date_str'] = df_corona_brio_clean['date'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
df_corona_brio_clean['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_corona_brio_clean['date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d')

df_agrupado_date_state = df_corona_brio_clean_2.groupby(['date_str','state_name'])['confirmed', 'deaths', 'estimated_population'].sum().reset_index()
df_agrupado_date_state.sort_values(by=['date_str','confirmed'], ascending=True)

with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codeforamerica/click_that_hood/master/public/data/brazil-states.geojson') as response:
  Brazil = json.load(response) # Javascrip object notation 

state_id_map = {}
for feature in Brazil ['features']:
  feature['id'] = feature['properties']['name']
  state_id_map[feature['properties']['sigla']] = feature['id']

fig = px.choropleth(df_agrupado_date_state,
                    locations='state_name',
                    geojson = Brazil,
                    color= df_agrupado_date_state['confirmed'],
                    color_continuous_scale= 'Reds',
                    hover_name='state_name',
                    hover_data=['confirmed', 'deaths'],
                    title='Number of cases over the time',
                    #animation_frame= 'date_str'
                    #animation_group= 'date_str'
                    
                    #animation_frame= df_agrupado_date_state['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                    #animation_group= df_agrupado_date_state['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                  )
fig.update_geos(fitbounds = "locations", visible = False)
fig.show()
```

I tried both *datetime* and *str* type for the date variable. I got the following fig without using *animate_frame*:

[image]

However, if I try any of these types, **they will not generate any graph**, and the **colab disconnects** to **restart**. I got the following log on colab while it tries to build the graph:

[image]

Somebody can help me with any idea?
Tkx

Comment: From the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64590033/animation-frame-lineplot-plotly-doesnt-work-python), adding the settings did not improve the situation. There was something about the 'nvidia-smi' folder not being found in the logs, so I selected GPU in the runtime changes, but it crashes with another error. I'm sorry I couldn't help you, but I have two pieces of information to offer.

Comment: Thank you for time @r-beginners. Unfortunately, it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

- there is a resource issue if you attempt to create animation frames for all dates.

  - Have limited to last dates using a constant
  - if you simplify the geometry the resource usage reduces significantly.  Have used **geopandas** to do this
- have aggregated data using named aggregations
- have use **featureidkey** to eliminate need to manipulate *geojson*
- have added **mapbox** solution too.  It's resource usage also depends highly on complexity of geometry

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

df_corona_brio_clean = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Yuri-Nassar/public_datasets/master/coronavirus/source_brasil_io/caso_covid_brio_filtered.csv",
    sep=";",
)
df_corona_brio_clean["date_str"] = df_corona_brio_clean["date"].apply(lambda x: str(x))
df_corona_brio_clean["date"] = pd.to_datetime(
    df_corona_brio_clean["date"], format="%Y-%m-%d"
)

with urlopen(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codeforamerica/click_that_hood/master/public/data/brazil-states.geojson"
) as response:
    Brazil = json.load(response)  # Javascrip object notation

SIMPLIFY=True
if SIMPLIFY:
    import geopandas as gpd
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(Brazil, crs="epsg:4326")
    gdf["geometry"] = gdf.to_crs(gdf.estimate_utm_crs()).simplify(5000).to_crs("epsg:4326")
    Brazil = gdf.__geo_interface__
    
df_agrupado_date_state = (
    df_corona_brio_clean.groupby(["date", "state"], as_index=False)
    .agg(
        **{
            **{c: (c, "first") for c in ["date_str", "state_name"]},
            **{c: (c, "sum") for c in ["confirmed", "deaths", "estimated_population"]},
        }
    )
    .sort_values(["date", "confirmed"])
)

MAX_DATES = 15
fig = px.choropleth(
    df_agrupado_date_state.loc[
        lambda d: d["date"].isin(d["date"].unique()[-MAX_DATES:])
    ],
    locations="state",
    geojson=Brazil,
    featureidkey="properties.sigla",
    color="confirmed",
    color_continuous_scale="Reds",
    hover_name="state_name",
    hover_data=["confirmed", "deaths"],
    title="Number of cases over the time",
    animation_frame="date_str",
)
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False).update_layout(margin={"l":0,"r":0,"t":30,"b":0})
```

[image]

#### mapbox

```
fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(
    df_agrupado_date_state.loc[
        lambda d: d["date"].isin(d["date"].unique()[-MAX_DATES:])
    ],
    locations="state",
    geojson=Brazil,
    featureidkey="properties.sigla",
    color="confirmed",
    color_continuous_scale="Reds",
    hover_name="state_name",
    hover_data=["confirmed", "deaths"],
    title="Number of cases over the time",
    animation_frame="date_str",
)
fig.update_layout(
    margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 30, "b": 0},
    mapbox={
        "style": "carto-positron",
        "zoom": 2,
        "center": {"lat": -14.2350, "lon": -51.9253},
    },
)
```

#### data sourcing

- in comments you note you are not getting each state for each date
- clearly not your data source does not support this
- change to this source which has cases by state in Brazil https://github.com/wcota/covid19br

```
df_corona_brio_clean = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wcota/covid19br/master/cases-brazil-states.csv")
df_corona_brio_clean = df_corona_brio_clean.loc[lambda d: d["state"].ne("TOTAL")]
df_corona_brio_clean["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_corona_brio_clean["date"])
df_corona_brio_clean["date_str"] = df_corona_brio_clean["date"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
df_agrupado_date_state = df_corona_brio_clean
MAX_DATES = 15
fig = px.choropleth(
    df_agrupado_date_state.loc[
        lambda d: d["date"].isin(d["date"].unique()[-MAX_DATES:])
    ],
    locations="state",
    geojson=Brazil,
    featureidkey="properties.sigla",
    color="newCases",
    color_continuous_scale="Reds",
    hover_name="state",
    hover_data=["newCases", "newDeaths"],
    title="Number of cases over the time",
    animation_frame="date_str",
)
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False).update_layout(margin={"l":0,"r":0,"t":30,"b":0})
```

Comment: Thank you for your time @rob. Your solution is different from what I'm trying to do. I don't know if I gotcha, but you said that `animation_frame` has an issue creating frames for all dates. Is it? Your solution shows only the frame with the current State and does not update the map like this example [here](https://python.plainenglish.io/how-to-create-a-interative-map-using-plotly-express-geojson-to-brazil-in-python-fb5527ae38fc). What I'm missing to adapt my code to look likes the example?

Comment: updated - not sure what you thought you'd get with your data source,  Burt a city only appears once in whole dataset.  there is no time series

Comment: Hi @rob, thx for your reply. I wonder to animate the first figure in the question by considering the date to update the **map (country)** by **state**. If I try to use the date in the animation_frame, the colab doesn't show me the map. If I don't use the animation_frame, I get the first figure which contains the last data update. Thus, I want to update the map over the time (frame) regarding each state at a date. Similar to yours, but updating the **whole map** instead of showing the state. I didn't figure out what is wrong with my code yet.

Comment: I am trying to build something like in this [tutorial](https://python.plainenglish.io/how-to-create-a-interative-map-using-plotly-express-geojson-to-brazil-in-python-fb5527ae38fc), but using the date (yy-mm-dd) as in your example.